# Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}\leq \frac{1}{100}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $\sqrt n-\sqrt{n-1}\le \frac{1}{100}$.

First I multiplied by the conjugate and got
$$\frac 1{\sqrt n + \sqrt{n-1}} \le \frac{1}{100},$$ or $\sqrt n+ \sqrt{n-1} \ge 100$. Now I squared both sides:
$$2n-1+2 \sqrt n \sqrt{n-1}\ge 100.$$ 
So $$\sqrt n (\sqrt n +\sqrt{n-1})\ge \frac {101}2.$$ However, we know that $\sqrt n+\sqrt{n-1}\ge 100$, so I substituted that:
$$\sqrt n (100) \ge \frac {101}{2}.$$
 However, if I solve for $n$ I get around  $.25$, and there is no lower positive integer. What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The latex commands "\leq" for $\leq$ and "\geq" for $\geq$ will do the trick.

Comment: Yea thanks I really need to learn latex

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting. You can also [see how I've edited your post here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/72e6aa50-0d67-4bcd-b56f-a7204f8e3dfb/view-source).

Comment: Also, *please* choose more descriptive, informative titles in the future.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: Thanks, I will

Comment: When you square both sides it is useful to square both sides.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Haha thanks I can't believe I missed that

Comment: Also, you cannot substitute an inequality into another inequality.  Suppose you know that $x>1$ and you're trying to solve $2x > 50$, you cannot just substitute 1 for $x$ and get $2>50$.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: Sorry I accidentally changed back the title and I don't see the rollback button. I'll try to change it back

Comment: @Ted: But it makes sense since we want to minimize $n$, meaning we want to minimize $sqrt(n)+sqrt(n−1)$, so it makes sense to substitute in the lowest possible value of $sqrt(n)+sqrt(n−1)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us stop temporarily at 
$$\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}\ge 100.\tag{1}$$ 
Maybe the algebraic manipulations can stop here. 
Note that (1) will  certainly be true if $2\sqrt{n-1}\ge 100$, that is, if $n-1 \ge 2500$, But it is conceivable that (1)  also holds  at $n=2500$. It doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. And by the way, Ted said in the comments that my substitution was not valid. What do you think about that? I think it's valid since we want to minimize $n$, meaning we want to minimize $sqrt(n)+sqrt(n-1)$, so it makes sense to substitute in the lowest possible value of $sqrt(n)+sqrt(n-1)$

Comment: @Ovi: Sure, you are right. The inequality you started with is equivalent to the more tractable $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}\ge 100$.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt n-\sqrt{n-1}\le\frac1{100}\implies \sqrt{n-1}\ge \sqrt n-\frac1{100}$

$$\text{On Squaring , }n-1\ge n+\frac1{100^2}-\frac{2\sqrt n}{100}$$

$$\implies \frac {\sqrt n}{50}\ge\frac1{100^2}+1$$